# Error calling forEach on an array literal in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

This code generates an error when I run it with node v6.9.2

```
var req = {}

['foo', 'bar'].forEach(prop => {
    console.log("prop: " + prop)
});
```

The error is: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined`

Why would that be? There doesn't seem to be anything syntactically wrong with what I'm doing. I note that if I add a semi-colon after the `var req = {}` line the error disappears, but I still don't understand why since I thought semi-colons were optional in JavaScript as long as each statement was on a separate line.

Comment: Node 6.10.3 seems to work fine, just FYI

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Automatic semicolon insertion has turned

```
var req = {}
['foo', 'bar']
```

into

```
var req = {}['foo', 'bar']
```

and of course `{}` doesn't contain a `'bar'` property (because `'foo', 'bar'` evaluates to `'bar'`).

`(undefined).forEach(...)` gets evaluated, which then leads to the error that you're seeing.

---

If you're relying on ASI, it's common practice to *prefix* lines beginning with `[]` or `()` with a semicolon:

```
var req = {}
;['foo', 'bar']
```

Comment: Very interesting! I didn't know about ASI, and it's propagation effects. Thanks!